# Cucumber feature file unable to locate glue code when clicking on Recalculate Steps and throws error message

Tags: selenium, eclipse-plugin, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am currently working on creating a Test Suite using Cucumber framework. I have created feature files for each of the functionality I have to test. 
The feature file never shows the conditions to be covered via glue code. On click of Recalculate steps it throws an error : An internal error occurred during: "Scanning for step definitions".
java.lang.NullPointerException

I tried to change the path of glue in the Test Runner class but it did not solve the problem as well. The feature can be executed without any issue and the code runs fine, only issue is feature files keep on stating that there is no matching glue code.

```
#OrderInteraction
@Orders
Feature: Validating Order functionality

  Background: Pre-requisites of Order Functionality
  Given WebDriver is initialized
  And Website is up and running
  When User Enter "Username" and "Password" as Credentials
  Then Validate User Login


Test Runner : 
package Cucumber;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "Features", glue= 
{"src/main/java/CucumberStepDefinitions"})

public class CucumberTestRunner {



}
```

I would like to find a way in which Cucumber feature files can recognize the glue code present. Feel free to guide me to a existing question which answers this or a documentation which will be of help.

Comment: I believe to be a bug in the Eclipse-Cucumber plugin. I've seen it as well. It's less tolerant of something that cucumber itself is fine with. Unfortunately, I don't have a solution either.

Comment: Hard for me to accept that it is issue which is not resolved yet. As it breaks the purpose of using Cucumber Feature File where I have say 50 Scenario and I want to take a look on how many of them are not covered. Thanks for the response Dan, appreciate it.

Comment: set the dryRun option to true and execute the runner. Any step that is undefined will be displayed.

Comment: How can I make sure my feature files read the Step Definitions when I click on Recalculate steps or maybe when I reopen the feature file. I want the code coverage of Test Steps to be shown in Feature File itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to find the solution to this issue. Issue lies with the cucumber plugin version, I referred to [Cucumber-Eclipse-Update-SiteSnapshot](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse-update-site-snapshot) for resolution.

The steps were as below :

1.From Eclipse, go to menu Help > Install New software

2.Work with: https://cucumber.github.io/cucumber-eclipse-update-site-snapshot

3.Select the check-box for Cucumber Eclipse Plugin

4.Select Next as per the instruction shown during installation.

5.Restart your Eclipse after completion of instruction.

Once the plugin was updated Feature file automatically scanned for steps and found the matching glue code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible solution in this discussion https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse/issues/303

Which basically says to make sure you don't have

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.*;
```

in your steps files, and to use

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
```

instead.

Which fixed it for me

Comment: Hi Lyndon, thanks for the input but unfortunately this didn't worked as well. On further research I found out that this was because of older version of eclipse plugin which needed an update.

Answer (score 0):

I found easy and safe solution.
Right click on project->properties-> select Glue code option from cucumber option-> check/uncheck already unchecked/checked checkbox "match regardless of parametertype" and click on apply.